# How to test a play framework controller that uses a custom bodyparser?

Tags: json, playframework, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to test a play framework 2.5.10 controller that uses a custom bodyparser and JSON validator:

```
class MessagingController {
  def validateJson[A : Reads] = parse.json.validate(
    _.validate[A].asEither.left.map(e => BadRequest(JsError.toJson(e)))
  )
  def createMessageThread() = Action(validateJson[InboundMessageThread]) { request => 
    Ok("OK") }
  }
```

When I run a simple test case on this I get an error:

```
For request 'POST /api/v1/messageThreads' [Invalid Json: No content to map due to 
end-of-input at [Source: akka.util.ByteIterator$ByteArrayIterator$$anon$1@5693d1d2; line: 1, column: 0]]
```

The test is:

```
  val fakeRequest = FakeRequest()
      .withHeaders(HeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/json")
      .withBody(Json.parse(
        s"""
           |{
           |  "participants": [
           |   {"id": $currentUserId, "isAdmin": false}
           |  ],
           |  "isGroupThread": false
           |}
    """.stripMargin))

  val result =  messagingController.createMessageThread()(fakeRequest).run()
  status(result) mustBe OK
```

If I change the controller's action to just `Action` and then validate the JSON in the body of the controller it works. I don't want to do that though because lots of my REST controllers need to parse JSON and using `validateJson[T]` reduces boilerplate. The code also works if I submit the same payload using curl.

How can I test this controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sort of request works:

```
val request = FakeRequest()
   .withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/json")
   .withBody(Json.fromJson[Place](body).get)
```

Comment: what is `body`? Is it string representation of the json?

Comment: jbrown - I am facing a similar issue. Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57596864/how-to-handle-action-which-returns-accumultorbytestring-result-in-unit-test

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this helps

```
 val postRequest = FakeRequest(POST, "/route/to/hit").withJsonBody(Json.obj(
    "participants" -> Json.arr(Json.obj("id" -> "currentUserId", "isAdmin" -> false)),
    "isGroupThread" -> false
  ))

  val result =  await(messagingController.createMessageThread()(postRequest))

  status(result) must be equalTo (FORBIDDEN)
```

Comment: This gives `415 was not equal to 403`. If I add the `withHeaders` call back in I get `400 was not equal to 403` as before...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling the Action with a JSON bodyparser, I'd suggest calling it with an ActionBuilder using an `AnyContent` body parser and then calling Json.validate from inside the body -- from there, you get a stack trace and see what's failed:

```
class MessagingController {      
  def createMessageThread() = Action { request => 
    request.json.validate[MessageThread] {
      case JsError(e) =>           
         logger.error(s"Failure parsing because $e")
         BadRequest(JsError.toJson(e))
      case JsSuccess(e) =>      
         Ok("OK")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea. But this returns "OK". If I add back in the JSON bodyparser with `def createMessageThread() = Action(parse.json)` it fails again. How do you have to write a test that uses a custom body parser?

Comment: OK I've got it working using `Action(parse.json)` but when I validate it using `Action.async(validateJson[InboundMessageThread])` it fails. I'll revise my question...